# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" при вызове своего обработчика события oninput

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `input`, при его изменении, т.е. по событию `oninput`, нужно выполнить скрипт с переданными данными, такой же скрипт выполняется при загрузке страницы, событие `$(document).ready`, для каждого найденного элемента с классом `products-num`, в этом случае все отлично, отрабатывает на ура, но в первом случае выдает ошибку `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

Вот инпут:

```
<input name="product-num" class="products-num" type="text" value="1" oninput="productTotal($(this),$('#product-price1'),$('#product-total1')">
```

Таких на странице может быть много

Bот скрипт:

```
function productTotal(num, price, total){
    var numVal = num.attr('value'), priceVal = price.attr('value'), totalVal = numVal * priceVal;
    total.attr('value', totalVal);
    orderSubTotal();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется не хватает скобочки, или это неправильно скопировано?

```
oninput="productTotal($(this),$('#product-price1'),$('#product-total1')"
```

Должно быть:

```
oninput="productTotal($(this),$('#product-price1'),$('#product-total1'))"
```

Comment: Видимо устал, спасибо что заметил, действительно проблема была только в этом.